# What is the best way to transfer data of Magento 2? + error "Unable to unserialize value."

Tags: magento2, database, import-products

I would like to change the server and move Magento 2.1.0 from server A to server B without any difference in data, theme, extensions, and configuration. only the domain will be a change from www.domaina.com to www.domainb.com. What is the best way to transfer it? I'm using Magento 2 CE.

edit: 
now I decide to buy a new theme. so, I install Magento CE 2.2.0 from application wizard in Plesk but when I import database I can't enter to the dashboard.

edit: after transfer to a new server and import database, I git this error when trying to enter to the dashboard: **There has been an error processing your request.** Unable to unserialize value

Answer (score 1):

Easy Steps:

1. Backup your database
2. Compress all file
3. Migrate all to new server
4. Import the database
5. Open local.xml location : app/etc/local.xml
6. Change following line 43 to 46, That is related to database configuration
   `<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
   <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
   <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
   <dbname><![CDATA[youdatabase_name]]></dbname>`
7. Open database and move table core_config_data
   change the value of this 2 items
   `web/unsecure/base_url
   web/secure/base_url`
   to this value `www.domainb.com`
8. Delete var dir
9. Reload [done]

Comment: is there a video tutorial?

Comment: and how tp compress all file? which files?

Comment: why did you note to delete var folder?

Answer (score 0):

**An overview:**

1/ Backup your database

2/ Backup your media

3/ Deploy your code from a code archive or your automatic deployment tool

4/ Copy all your media

5/ Update your configuration (Mysql, Redis, ElasticSearch) from env.php

6/ Import your database

7/ Execute magento cli commands : deploy statics / compile
    code / set production mode / reindex / generate image resize if you do not backup the
    generated product image variations / flush cache

8/ Test your site

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: yes, I need more details. or can you explain with an image or is there a video tutorial?

Comment: Sorry I do not have time to do this stuff. But if you have precise question, I can detail it.

Comment: how to backup a media?

Comment: You need to backup the pub/media folder

Comment: steps 1, 2, 4  and 6 are done.

Comment: can you explain steps 3 and 5 for (Redis, ElasticSearch)? and when I try to enter to the admin area. username and password are not accepted.

Comment: If you are using Redis and/or ElasticSearch, you need to setup correctly the server IP and PORT of your new environment. For step 3/ basically it is only a copy paste of your code, but you can use a deployment tool, I recommend you to use Ansible.

Comment: username and password are not accepted, and I'm sure they are correct. how can i fix this problem

Comment: Username and password for what ? Can you be more precise.

Comment: I import database and get this error "Invalid entity_type specified" can you help? how to fix that error?